# last word getting clipped/truncated in jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a page of information- String
When the content is in JNI (**cpp dll**) i am able to see the entire content, however when we see the same string in java, the last word is clipped/truncated.  So in order to debug, I  am trying to write the content in JNI to a log txt file.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_native_ExeCOM_GetResultDetails
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    _bstr_t bstrIntermediate( execution->GetResultDetails());

    //WriteContentToLog((LPCTSTR)bstrIntermediate); //Able to write this to log (no loss)

    CString strFinal;
    strFinal.Format(_T("%s"), (LPCTSTR)bstrIntermediate);

     //WriteContentToLog((LPCTSTR)strFinal); //Able to write this to log (no loss)

    return  env->NewStringUTF(strFinal);
}



using namespace std;
#define FILE "C:\\Temp\\debug.txt"
ofstream DEBUG_STRM;
void WriteContentToLog(const std::string &msg){ 
    DEBUG_STRM.open (FILE,fstream::app);    
    DEBUG_STRM <<msg<<"\n"; DEBUG_STRM.close();
}
```

After the jstring is returned, if we analyze the same from java side, last word from the content is getting clipped/truncated.

I want to see if any truncation is happening in the last line  **"env->NewStringUTF(strFinal)"** . 
1. Can I write the content returned by last line to a log file ?
2. Why only the last word is getting truncated  (as I have tested for size)?

could someone help me.

Comment: Could be related to missing "flush()" of the output stream?

Comment: tried flush(), not much help.

Comment: Please give an example of the data expected and what's being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Your string data could be exposing flaws in your string conversions, which could be vastly simplified.

A Java string is a counted sequence of code-units of UTF-16 encoded Unicode characters.

A `BSTR` is essentially the same. (Usually, that is. It ultimately depends on code creating the BSTR.)

`NewStringUTF` accepts a 0x00-terminated sequence of code-units of [modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) encoded Unicode characters. If that's not the nature of the string you are passing, it's not the right function to use.

I recommend that you use `NewString`, passing it a pointer to the `BSTR` characters and its length.

A good introduction to dealing with strings is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets—No Excuses](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.

UPDATE:

Your JNI function could be written as:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_native_ExeCOM_GetResultDetails
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    BSTR bstr = execution->GetResultDetails();
    jstring str = env->NewString(bstr, SysStringLen(bstr));
    SysFreeString(bstr);  // assuming GetResultDetails transfers ownership
    return str;
}
```

To find out what the BSTR actually contains, dump it with this function. Note: Bytes are printed as ASCII characters for orientation purposes only. The implementation above assumes that it is a typical BSTR, that is, it contains UTF-16 encoded Unicode characters.

```
void DumpBstr( BSTR bstr )
{
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)bstr;
    unsigned int *length = (((unsigned int *)bstr) - 1);
    unsigned short *terminator =(unsigned short *)(buffer + *length);
    UINT len = SysStringLen(bstr);
    UINT byteLen = SysStringByteLen(bstr);
    printf("Dumping BSTR at %p\n", bstr);
    printf("    %s\n", (char *)bstr);
    printf("    SysStringLen %i\n", len);    // A BSTR created with SysAllocStringByteLen can have an odd byte length. SysStringLen presumes an even number of bytes.
    printf("    SysStringByteLen %i\n", byteLen);    
    if (bstr==NULL) { printf("    NULL is equivalent to an empty string. [VB can pass a BSTR this way and SysStringLen et al account for this]"); return;}
    printf("    Hidden length field %i\n", *length);
    {
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0; i < *length; i++)
        {
            printf("    Byte %02X   %c\n", *(buffer + i), *(buffer + i));
        }
    }
    printf("    Hidden terminator field %04X\n", *terminator);
}
```

Comment: Tom, thanks for the reply.
I tried to use 'NewString' passing it a pointer to the _bstr_t and length but with no help. However I found a similar issue in Oracle JNI forum and found the second resolution helpful. I am including the link below, please have a look at it and let me know your thoughts:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1547869&tstart=1652

Comment: Tom, I am able to use your jni function and it did help resolve the issue. However, I have couple of questions, 

1. shouldn't we avoid using raw types like BSTR ?
2. heard that SysFreeString has some jvm crash issues in Win2008 ?
I am little apprehensive here.

Comment: 2. I haven't heard that--do you have links to bug reports? It could be just someone misusing APIs involving BSTR. If the function that creates the BSTR expects you to free it then you'll have a memory leak if you don't. 1. It depends on what you are working with. Since you have a function that returns a BSTR, you have to start with that. Wrapping it in a C++ object doesn't give any advantage in that simple JNI function. The Sys*String* API functions are pretty simple. On the other hand, if you had to concatenate strings, I would wrap or convert BSTRs rather than write my own BSTR functions.

Comment: TOM, I was doing some detailed testing, and found that if the content contains certain characters like 'left arrow'(\u000D), 'right arrow'.

jstr = env->NewString((const jchar *)bstr, SysStringLen(bstr));

gives error

. These characters seem to be multibyte

Comment: I was copying those 'left arrow' and 'right arrow' special characters from putty log,

Comment: You need to check again the nature of the string you are copying. Using the `DumpBstr` function you should see two or four bytes per character. Latin letters should be easily discernable and appear as two bytes, the first being 0x00, e.g. ["a"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm)  is 0x00 0x61. You are seeing left arrows due to Putty's or your font's representation of a carriage return.